# Bag-of-words in CRF++

Tags: crf++

What is the syntax for a bag-of-words feature in CRF++ template file?

Template example:

```
#Unigrams
U00:%x[0,0]
U01:%x[0,1]
U02:%x[1,0]

#Bigrams
B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is this way:

```
#Unigrams
U00:%x[0,0]
U00:%x[0,1]
U00:%x[1,0]

#Bigrams
B
```

Using the same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of bag-of-words might be like this:

```
#Unigrams
U00:%x[0,0]/%x[0,1]/%x[1,0]

#Bigrams
B
```

[Description of CRF++ using a template of CoNLL 2000 for bag-of-words](http://crfpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html?source=navbar)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct template for using Bag of (3) Words :

```
#Unigrams
U00:%x[-1,0]
U00:%x[0,0]
U00:%x[1,0]

#Bigrams
B
```

Note that the identifiers are same (U00).

```
[-1,0] -> previous word
[0,0] -> current word
[1,0] -> next word
```